# Changing Group Policy on windows machines using .NET or via installer

Tags: windows, group-policy

The machine I work with is connected to the desktop via USB cable and there are certain rules that have to be enforced in order to make sure that the machine is running properly and does not go to sleep all of a sudden and some other policies I met. I am thinking of shipping the Local Policy files with the installer to enforce those policies on the end user since this way, if they do end up changing some settings, they can always go back and reinstall the original file. However, after doing some research, I was not able to find anything that suggests that it can either be done through application (I use .NET Framework) or through install files (such as .iss) - all of the options I found suggest manually going into Policy Editor and changing the policies there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to programmatically change Local GP settings, there are multiple ways you could accomplish this

- Method 1: One way to accomplish is to create a .NET project and utilize Oliver Wayman's library to modify Local group policy. The library gives you the advantage of not having to mess directly with registery settings and simplifies alot of the steps involved .[Oliverwyman LGP Library](https://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/open-source/)
  The code would look similar to the snippet provided in one of the examples:

  ```
  var gpo = new ComputerGroupPolicyObject();

  const string keyPath = @"SOFTWAREPoliciesMicrosoftWindows NTTerminal Services";

  using (var machine = gpo.GetRootRegistryKey(GroupPolicySection.Machine))
  {

      using (var terminalServicesKey = machine.CreateSubKey(keyPath))
      {

       terminalServicesKey.SetValue("SecurityLayer", 00000000,  RegistryValueKind.DWord);
      }
  }
  gpo.Save();
  ```
- Method 2: Using the .NET IGroupPolicyObject Interface
  This method will involve more tedious coding but it is possible to accomplish what you need through this interface by using it in a .NET Porject.
- Method 3: Using tool or program that could create automated Local GP rules.
  unfortunately the only tool I could find was from sdmsoftware and it is not free. [Sdm Software GPAE](https://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/)